# How do I find $f(0)$, $f'(0)$, and $f'(x)$ given $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+x^2y+xy^2$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

How can I find $f(0)$, $f'(0)$, and $f'(x)$ given that

$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+x^2y+xy^2$

and

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Let $x=y=0$ we get $f(0)=0$
- We have

$$f'(x)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(y)}{y}+x^2+xy=1+x^2$$

Comment: Sorry, I meant the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ goes to $0$ is $1$.

Comment: I don't understand how letting $x=y=0$ makes $f(0)=0$. Doesn't that give $f(0)=f(0)+f(0)$? Is it that $f(0)=f(0)+f(0)$ implies $f(0)=0$ because the only value that satisfies $z=z+z$ is $z=0$?

Comment: Yes that's right!